# How to know the user who created a specific item in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Is it possible to get the id of the user who created a specific item, no matter what it, in Django? I have a site where when the users are authenticated can access a form and submit a new item. Can I retrieve who created what without adding an extra 'submitted by'

```
Event.objects.filter(owner=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

(which gives me `name 'self' is not defined` )?

Comment: You have to save the information of  the`AUTH_USER` *somehow* in your `Event` model.

Comment: OK, I thought there was a way of accessing that information without adding a new field. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the information without adding a new field, but you can have a look at this library [django-audit-log](https://github.com/vvangelovski/django-audit-log) for easy tracking. It will add  `created_by` and `modified_by` fields and maintain them.